# How to use Angular's limitTo in conjunction with bootstrap responsiveness?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building an application using the responsive utilities provided by Bootstrap backed by AngularJS. Consider the following scenario. I'm displaying information in a grid like fashion. On larger displays, the grid has dimensions of `2 x 3`. On medium displays, the grid dimensions switches to `2 x 2`, and on smaller displays, it switches to `1 x 2`. Pagination is implemented to allow paging through more items.

As you can see, due to the dimensional changes, the number of items I am displaying at any given time may change (6 items in large, 4 in medium, and 2 in small).

```
<div ng-repeat="row in items">
  <div ng-repeat="item in row" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6"></div>
</div>
```

Items constructed by:

```
var breakOn = 3;  // This could vary depending on dimensions
var items = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += breakOn) {
  items.push(data.slice(i, i + breakOn));
}
```

I default to showing 6 items (`2 x 3`), so obviously in smaller form factors, the items begin to overflow because it's attempting to render too many.

**My question is**: is it possible to use something like `limitTo` to somehow limit the number of items I am showing (depending on the dimensions)? Does a pattern exist to handle a situation such as this?

Answer (score 1):

BootStrap will happily go to the next row for you. Just leave all your items in a flat array (`allItems`), and use

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="item in allItems" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        {{ item }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Suppose you have 8 items. On large displays, they will look like

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8
```

on medium displays, they will look like

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve this exact situation. This works to hide extra items on smaller displays:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
    li:nth-child(n+5) {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

So I have 6 elements in the array being used by ng-repeat: on md and lg all are displayed, but on sm and xs displays only the first 4 items will be visible.

This is not ideal as it doesn't fully solve the problem. Say I want to only display full rows - so on lg displays it will have either one row of 3 items or two rows of 3 items, on sm screen it will have either one row of 2 items or two rows of 2 items.

We can do this:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
    // hide any more than 4 items on small screens
    li:nth-child(n+5) {
        display: none;
    }

    // if we have 3 items, only display the first 2
    ul.count-3 li:nth-child(n+3) {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media(min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    // if we have 4 or 5 items, hide any more than the first 3
    ul.count-4, ul.count-5 {
        li:nth-child(n+4) {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the angular template:

```
<ul ng-class="'count-' + items.length">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:6" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"></li>
</ul>
```